# Need to have a Trigger on Table with Encrypted Column in SQL Server that inserts a new record for each update into Archive Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, triggers, sql-server-2017

I have a table similar to following schema in SQL Server 2017:

Table `Sample` in the main database where `TaxID` column is encrypted using SQL Server "Always Encrypted" feature:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample]
(
    [CreatedDt] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastModDt] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyTaxName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [TaxID] [varchar](15) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = 
    [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

Then we have another table with same schema in archive database for history purposes with `TaxID` encrypted.

This is the table `Sample` in the `Main_Archive` database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample]
(
    [CreatedDt] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastModDt] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyArchiveID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyTaxName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [TaxID] [varchar](15) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = 
    [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

Now, we want to have a trigger on the main `Sample` table that inserts a new record into the archive `Sample` table for every update.

The trigger for the `Sample` table in the main database is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_iud_Sample] 
ON [dbo].[Sample]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @CurrDt AS SMALLDATETIME
    SELECT @CurrDt = GETDATE()

    DECLARE @CurrYear AS INT
    SELECT @CurrYear = YEAR(@CurrDt)

    UPDATE Sample
    SET LastModDt = @CurrDt,
        CreatedDt = CASE WHEN d.CompanyID IS NULL THEN @CurrDt ELSE Sample.CreatedDt END
    FROM inserted i WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN deleted d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.CompanyID= i.CompanyID
    WHERE Sample.CompanyID = i.CompanyID 

    INSERT INTO [Main_Archive].[dbo].Sample
        SELECT CreatedDt, LastModDt, CompanyID, CompanyName, CompanyTaxName, TaxID, Active
        FROM deleted
END

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sample] ENABLE TRIGGER [tr_iud_Sample]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vendor] DISABLE TRIGGER [tr_iud_Sample]
GO
```

But this fails and I get this error:

> Msg 4920, Level 16, State 0, Line 50
> Operand type clash: varchar(15) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'NCI_COMMON') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2' is incompatible with varchar

Is there a way to have a trigger on encrypted table and if so, how to achieve the
desired functionality?

Also, if SQL Server currently does not support that, is there any work around to achieve that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you sure CEK_Auto1 encyption keys are identical on both servers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy the encrypted column to another database SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519867/copy-the-encrypted-column-to-another-database-sql-server-2012)

Comment: @Ehsan Yes, CEK_Auto1 Encryption keys are identical on both servers and I also checked the encrypted data of same value to make sure they are the same.

Comment: @Ehsan Thanks for suggesting the link "Copy the encrypted column to another database...." but it uses Symmetric Key Encryption where as my question is related to "SQL Always Encrypted" encryption. 
I even tried to use DecryptByKey function but it did not work with my case.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Always Encrypted` your SQL Server version [System-Versioned Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can make your table system-versioned and leave the work of maintaining the history to the SQL Server Engine (also, when you are changing your table design, the engine will mitigate the changes to the history table).

Temporal tables can be [queried](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15) using special clauses and bring to you new ways for analyzing historical data.

One disadvantage I have faced is that the history table columns must match the target table ones - so, if you need to have a `ModifiedBy` column in the history, you must change your application to populate such value in the original table.